# Detecting last row in tableView section and removing separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have tableView with multiply sections. I want to have separators between row but not want have separator under last row in section. How can I achieve it?

My code removes also a inner separators.

```
NSInteger totalRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
if (indexPath.row == totalRow -1)
{
    //v1 of code
    UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    CGRect r = cell.bounds;
    r.origin.y = r.origin.y + r.size.height - 2;
    l.frame = r;
    l.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:l];
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    //v2 of code
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10000.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1000);
```

_http://i60.tinypic.com/15xpyqp.png

I create cells like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cellL;
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
    {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PopPushCellIdentifier";
                PopPushCell *cell = (PopPushCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                cell.pushTypeOn = YES;
                cell.style = 5;
                cell.titleLabel.text = [self returnTitleForCellWithTag:cell];
                return cell;
            }
                break;

            case 1:
            {
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TextFieldCellIdentifier";
                TextFieldCell *cell = (TextFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                cell.style = 4;
                cell.titleLabel.text = [self returnTitleForCellWithTag:cell];
                return cell;
            }
                break;
```

Comment: What exactly not working? Have you try debugging the code?

Comment: If I add white separator at the bottom of cell with code v1 - it adds in inner cells too. If I set inset with code v2 ti bottom cells - it set to inner too. See image

Comment: do you use custom cell separator or a built-in one?

Comment: and this image   _http://i.imgur.com/fOAOJqK.png

Comment: @sha, no, it just for more visible sample

Comment: If you want to hide built-in separator - set separatorInsets edge (left or right) to the size of the cell. Don't change top/bottom insets.

Comment: it not works. I have it even if I set self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0, 0.0);;

Comment: where is the code you are showing in the first quote? It should be in cellForIndexPath

Comment: yes, I tried to do it  in cellForIndexPath and in willDisplayCell

Comment: It should work in cellForIndexPath. You're doing something wrong... Please post complete code for cellForIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to insert a 1 pixel height UIView on your cells. Having a reference to it (linking on Interface Builder) and setting it hidden or not on your delegate.

Comment: it not works. I have it even if I set     self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0, 0.0);;

Comment: This approach should work but you will have to disable the default separators on UITableView

Comment: And don't forget to give the UIView a backgroundcolor

Comment: Thanks for completing my explanation